# What's difference between View view and View v?

Tags: android, android-studio

In courses of Android Basics on Udacity, (View view) and (View v) were used interchangeably.

```
public void methodName(View view){}
public void methodName2(View v){}
```

Are they the same? I'm curious because one might act a little different than the other and they are changing the view to v to view again for a specific purpose.

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: Just a suggestion: you will probably benefit more if you learn some basic Java before tackling Android.

Comment: You posted a question 2 years ago in which you had an app!! And now you ask this question? 
I would say you need some programming lessons first. There is no difference between those statements

Comment: Oh Henry, sorry, I'm just new too. I now know that View view isn't different to int number, for example.

Comment: Ivan, y r u stalking me? Also, I am taking a programming class now. That question is a question when I am still 13 years old. I thought I could just jump to copying code and asking questions back then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. They are exactly the same. The only difference is that parameter formal names are different: `v` and `view`. Use whatever you like and makes your code more readable.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! But, why are they written differently? Is it a shortcut thing?

Comment: If they're both from the same course, then the author was just sloppy/inconsistent. From different courses, it's just a stylistic choice. Some people use `v` because it's shorter, others use `view` because that's what Android Studio gives as the first tab-complete option for the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

both view and v are just variables name. they will both act the same. you can also write
methodName3(View name) and "name" will still act the same as "view" and "v".

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that! Does this mean that I can use another variable name?

Answer (score 1):

Both are the object of `View` Class.

Have a look at [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)